# Bootstrap NavBar With impress.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, impress.js

Is it possible to add a boostrap nav bar to a impress.js site? I'm having trouble integrating it, and I don't understand how to use multiple CSS style sheets for my site (first time web builder).

Any thoughts? All ideas are welcome, since I'm a moron with this stuff.

Comment: just externally link to both css sheets in 2 different lines separately?

Comment: Is the problem solved? If yes, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at http://www.scala-tour.com/#/welcome
I've just stumbled upon it and they're using impress.js and a bootstrap menu together.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link tag in head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

And let the `<nav></nav>` outside of `<div id="impress"></div>`.